# Google API Level 18 emulator "This app won't run unless you update Google Play services"

Tags: android

I am running an emulator with Google API level 18 but whenever I open my google maps based application I get the error message "This app won't run unless you update Google Play services".

How can I get google play services to run on my emulator? I have looked at other stackoverflow questions but they say to use the latest API, which I already am.

**EDIT: It is worth noting i am using the support library**

EDIT: Screenshot of my emulator setup:

[image]

Comment: This: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html just says `he Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher`

Comment: Open Android SDK manager, navigate to Extras & check if you have latest Google Play Services installed

Comment: I have the latest Google Play Services

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup an emulator with the API level you need + the Google API! For every API level there are 2 version of ROM! One with Google APIs and one without! If you choose the first you will be ok to run any app that uses Google Play Services!

Comment: How do I setup an emulator with both?

Comment: If you setup an emulator for API level 18 with Google APIs you will be fine! Just go to your SDK download the latest API level and then go to your Android Virtual Device manager and choose Google APIs 18 as the target for your device. After it you are good to go!

Comment: this is what I have done, but I still get this message, I am using the support library though

Comment: Post a screenshot of your emulator details please!

Comment: The app opens and where the map should be displayed there is a “This app won't run unless you update Google Play services” message

Comment: Can you please post your code for this check and even try to hit that button to see what happens!

Answer (score 1):

You should create emulator with target version **Google APIs** - API level 18, start it and add Google account (System settings - Add account - Google)

Comment: I am still getting the same issue, even after adding an account

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem once as i tried to feed my app with dummy-locationdata via emulator.

There is still no map-support for the emulator, though you can workaround and get it running the hard way!

in my eyes, best tutorial for your purpose is [THIS TUTORIAL.](http://nemanjakovacevic.net/blog/english/2012/12/06/how-to-make-android-google-maps-v2-work-in-android-emulator/)

Answer (score 0):

On a device, you need to have Google Play Services intalled. I'm not sure if it's possible to have it installed on an emulator. You can try searching for workarounds. But I've had this problem before, I just ended up using a real device.