# Google Play Services Missing on Android 2.2 or 4.1.2 Emulator while using Google Maps Api V2

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-emulator

Hey I am trying to use google maps on my emulator even though I’ve installed google play services library when I run the app it says

“This app won’t run without google play services which are missing from your phone”

on LogCat I get the warning about it but not really sure why I am getting this.

my MainActivity.java

```
package com.mapsmaps;

import android.os.Bundle;


import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GoogleMap mapa = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mapsmaps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<permission
    android:name="com.mapsmaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.mapsmaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />F

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    >
    <activity
        android:name="com.mapsmaps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBdbj4iXi0SijKjJDrJw5RigtSpQcaID7Q" />
</application>
```

LogCat

```
01-31 11:10:41.404: D/dalvikvm(451): DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/content/res/Configuration;.smallestScreenWidthDp
```

01-31 11:10:41.404: W/dalvikvm(451): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 24
01-31 11:10:41.404: D/dalvikvm(451): VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x0012
01-31 11:10:41.404: D/dalvikvm(451): VFY: dead code 0x0014-0018 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b (Landroid/content/res/Resources;)Z
01-31 11:10:41.443: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(451): Google Play services is missing.
01-31 11:10:41.454: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(451): Google Play services is missing.
01-31 11:10:41.464: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(451): Google Play services is missing.
01-31 11:10:41.464: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(451): Google Play services is missing.
01-31 11:10:41.475: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(451): Google Play services is missing.
01-31 11:10:41.494: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(451): Google Play services is missing.
01-31 11:10:41.504: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(451): Google Play services is missing.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test your Google Play Services implementation with your app your emulator should support Google APIs.

You can easily do this by creating a new Emulator Virtual Device and adding as a target your desired Google APIs Level image, for example: Google APIs - API level 18

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test your Google Play Services implementation with your app your emulator should support Google APIs.

You can easily do this by creating a new Emulator Virtual Device and adding as a target your desired Google APIs Level image, for example: *Google APIs - API level 18*

Also refer to this question too for more informations: [Google API Level 18 emulator "This app won't run unless you update Google Play services"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315942/google-api-level-18-emulator-this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-s/18316044#18316044)